# AxMsRdpClient9 - How to determine the server side API support

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, mstsc

Some of the AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting APIs can only operate based on the version of the server that it is connected to.  For example 'UpdateSessionDisplaySettings' cannot be used unless the server is 2012R2 or later.

Is there a way to determine the OS of the server (or some other technique) so we know which APIs can be used?

Thanks,